# How to clean up git commits that are not the HEAD of any branch or tag?

Tags: git

We frequently use `rebase`, `amend`, and other operations on our git repository that have created a lot of "unused" or intermediate commits.

More formally, unused commits are those that meet all of these criteria:

- They do **not** have any child commits AND
- They are **not** the `HEAD` of any branch (local or remote)
- They are **not** the `HEAD` of any tag (local or remote)

Is there an easy way to (1) identify this list of commits and (2) permanently remove them?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you in a hurry to drop them? Normally those objects get garbage collected after a while because even if there are no branches/tags pointing to them, there are other pointers still using them.. for a while (like reflog references). Anyway, you can use `git gc --aggresive --prune=now` but take a look at `git help gc` or https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Answer (score 0):

```
git fsck --unreachable
```

will show you unreachable commits that will be removed when running `git prune`. You can invoke

```
git prune
```

manually to remove all dangling objects.

Normally git garbage collection will automatically take care of that for you after a while. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38850390/2082964), `git gc` runs:

- git-prune
- git-reflog
- git-repack
- git-rerere

Probably `git prune` does most of the cleaning that you need. You can also invoke `git gc` manually with more strict parameters, something like:

```
git gc --aggresive --prune=now
```

But make sure to read the [documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc) so as to tweak this command to fit your exact use.